# How can I import multiple items from a module and rename them in Python?

Tags: python, module

I want to import `atan` and `degree` from `math` and rename them both.

I have tried using this:

```
from math import atan,degree as t,z
```

But that gives `ImportError: cannot import name 'z'`.

I did a number of Google searches for "import multiple modules and rename", but all were fruitless. The Python manual hasn't helped - the page on imports doesn't explain this (as far as I can tell).

How can I import multiple items from a module, and rename them?

Comment: Related: *[David Beazley - Modules and Packages: Live and Let Die! - PyCon 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oTh1CXRaQ0)* (tutorial with a lot about the import statement. It doesn't really start before 6 min 40 secs.)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You have to use the `as` for each item:

```
from math import atan as t, degree as z
```

This imports and renames them all.

Answer (score 11):

The [Python Reference Manual](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) does, in fact, cover this. It says, in its description for the `import` statement:

```
import_stmt     ::=  "import" module ["as" name] ( "," module ["as" name] )*
                     | "from" relative_module "import" identifier ["as" name]
                     ( "," identifier ["as" name] )*
                     | "from" relative_module "import" "(" identifier ["as" name]
                     ( "," identifier ["as" name] )* [","] ")"
                     | "from" module "import" "*"
```

Now, this notation is a little confusing at first glance, but as spend time with programming languages you will become more familiar with it. It is commonly refered to as "BNF" (which stands for *Backus-Naur Form*). Most programming language references will use some version of it.

From the sample above, we see the following symbols that could do with some explanation:

- Vertical bar or Pipe character ( `|` ) -- *this is used to separate alternatives*
- The asterisk / star character ( `*` ) -- *this means that the preceding (usually enclosed statement) is repeated zero or more times*
- Square brackets (`[` and `]`) -- *these indicate that the enclosed portion which occurs is optional, so included zero or one times*.
- Parenthesis (`(` and `)`) -- *these are used to group statements for the asterisk to take affect on*

Cutting down the reference above to what you seem interested in, we have:

```
"from" relative_module "import" identifier ["as" name]
                     ( "," identifier ["as" name] )*
```

**TL;DR** Which, for your example given, leads to the legal statement being

```
from math import atan as t, degree as z
```