# Pandas source code import multiple modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, cython, pandas-groupby

I was looking at the pandas source code [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2e38d5552a5c7b2c0091cecddd483f4f08ad1d2c/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py), and I found the following statement a little bit weird:

```
from pandas._libs import NaT, groupby as libgroupby, iNaT, lib, reduction
```

It seems that it imported Nat and groupby, which are two libraries, as multiple modules (libgroupby, iNaT, lib, reduction).

1. I went to the `pandas._libs` library [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/tree/2e38d5552a5c7b2c0091cecddd483f4f08ad1d2c/pandas/_libs), but I didn't find any model with name `NaT`. There is indeed a `groupby.pyx`, which I assume is the `groupby` library?
2. Can the number of imported libraries be less than the imported modules? How does that work? From my past understanding, we can do `import a as b`, but we cannot do `import a as b, c`.

Comment: The second part of your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865421/how-can-i-import-multiple-items-from-a-module-and-rename-them-in-python)

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for pointing me to that direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from `pandas._libs` it actually imported 5 method/class/module:

1. NaT,
2. grouby as libgroupy (so in your script you will now use libgroupy)
3. iNaT
4. lib
5. reduction

---

Now `NaT` and `iNaT` indeed doesn't exists in the `_libs` folder, but it won't give an import error because they are imported from somewhere else in `__init__.py` of _libs.
`__init__.py` of a package implicitly executes whenever something is imported from that package or it's subpackages.
So the `__init__.py` inside `_libs` will execute, where `NaT, iNaT etc.` is imported from package `.tslibs` hence making them available for import from `.libs` package too.
Now if you will look for `NaT` or `iNaT` in the .tslibs folder you will won't find it, but if you will look at the `__init__.py` of `.tslibs` you will see here `NaT` and `iNaT` is imported from `.nattype`, so if you look inside that file this time you will find the definition of `NaT` and `iNaT` in there.

You can take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=__init__#regular-packages) for better explanation

---

You can import it like this and then it might be easier for you to understand whats going on:

```
from pandas._libs import NaT, iNaT, lib, reduction, groupby as libgroupby
```

This import will do exactly the same as what the import statement in your question does.

Comment: Thanks! Very precise answer!