# Python import two distinct methods as

Tags: python-3.x, import

I have two python scripts: `my_helper` and `my_consumer_script`

`my_helper`:

```
MY_CONSTANT_THE_ANSWER_FROM_HHGTTG = 42 
MY_CONSTANT_THE_SMALLEST_POSITIVE_COMPOSITE_NUMBER = 4
```

`my_consumer_script`:

```
from my_helper import MY_CONSTANT_THE_ANSWER_FROM_HHGTTG as h2gt2g
from my_helper import MY_CONSTANT_THE_SMALLEST_POSITIVE_COMPOSITE_NUMBER as min_composite

print(h2gt2g + min_composite)  # 46
```

This fails:

```
from my_helper import MY_CONSTANT_THE_ANSWER_FROM_HHGTTG, MY_CONSTANT_THE_SMALLEST_POSITIVE_COMPOSITE_NUMBER  as h2gt2g, min_composite

print(h2gt2g + min_composite)
```

How can combine two import as statements into one?

Comment: Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865421/how-can-i-import-multiple-items-from-a-module-and-rename-them-in-python Hope it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, import command is more from SQL language so you import first one and then the others

`from my_helper import MY_CONSTANT_THE_ANSWER_FROM_HHGTTG as h2gt2g, MY_CONSTANT_THE_SMALLEST_POSITIVE_COMPOSITE_NUMBER  as min_composite`